# Implement voice identification to log into a system

Tags: java, voice-recognition

Recently I'm working on a college project but I wanna do some additions to the login and that it's as the title said add voice recognition, it's possible  to verify if the voice it's almost the same? And if that can be do, what will be the best option to start?

Comment: Start with giving the question a readable title, not a collection of tags.

Comment: Sorry my bad, im gonna change the title, thanks

Comment: Voice recognition is ***incredibly*** broad.  You're looking at a field that has something on the order of 25 years of existence with imperfections at every corner.  You're not going to be able to sort those out in a college project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outline of this project is pretty simple:

1. Implement voice recognition algorithm with the language of your choice. You can go with simple GMM classifier to distinguish between voices of different users. The algorithm is described [here](https://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/developing-an-isolated-word-recognition-system-in-matlab.html).
2. Once algorithm starts to work, integrate it into login authentication module. We once did that for face recognition, you can find the code sample [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pam-face-authentication/source/default/source). You just need to replace face authentication with voice authentication library.

It's not a trivial project but it should work.